# Ternary Operator in Razor View of MVC3 and Checked Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ternary-operator, checked

I use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" checked="@(item.HasAccess ? "checked" : "")"/>
```

This worked correctly: I mean when `HasAccess` is `true` then `checked="checked"` and when 
`HasAccess` is `false` then `checked=""` but always the `checkbox`s checked, how can I use ternary operator and handle `checked` attribute correctly?

Comment: Where are you using this code? If you posted more of the View the more context I have to see would help solve the problem

Comment: @Chris I've actually only seen that in grid components or controls, never in an MVC view where you have helpers to leverage from, but ok :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, in razor V1, you must do it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" @(item.HasAccess ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
```

This is because in the HTML world, the mere presence of the attribute at all, regardless of the value, tells the browser to check the box.

In Razor V2, this will be less of a problem. See the conditional attributes section of the article below:

http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/

Comment: This one is a good alternative (has a sample with checkbox) : http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/conditional-attributes-in-razor-view-engine-and-asp.net-mvc-4